# Creating a function for easier use of the Strava API from the rStrava package in R does not work but the code outside a function works fine

Tags: r, strava

I work as an exercise physiologist, and I use the rStrava package for creating an API between R and my Strava account for doing session analyses. The API works fine on its own (outside a function), but inside a function it does not run. In the post, there is an example of the code outside and inside a function.

Expected behavior from the function is that it returns a data frame called by what I give to `df_name`, with a `resolution` of either `"low", "medium"` or `"high"` on the session ID, `id`, that I get from my Strava account.

Beneath is the standalone code (not in a function) that works. Note that I have edited out my personal information using #'s.

```
library(rStrava)
    
# Data from my personal Strava API
    
app_name <- "#"
app_client_id <- "#"
app_secret <- "#"
    
# The token that makes the connection to my Strava data
    
strava_token <- httr::config(token = strava_oauth(app_name,
                                                      app_client_id,
                                                      app_secret,
                                                      app_scope = "activity:read_all"))
    
# Accessing the data
    
my_acts <- get_activity_list(strava_token)
id <- {#} # This is the ID from Strava that is unique to a session
strava_data <- get_activity_streams(my_acts,
                                        strava_token,
                                        id = id,
                                        resolution = "high")
```

**The problem** is that if I wrap this into a function, the expected behaviour is not achieved. This is the code inside a function:

```
generate_strava_session_data <- function(id, 
                                         df_name,
                                         resolution){
                                         
  
  library(rStrava)
  library(tidyverse)
  
  # Data from my personal Strava API
  
  app_name <- "#"
  app_client_id <- "#"
  app_secret <- "#"
  
  # The token that makes the connection to my Strava data
  
  strava_token <- httr::config(token = strava_oauth(app_name,
                                                    app_client_id,
                                                    app_secret,
                                                    app_scope = "activity:read_all"))

# These five print lines were added to debug

  print(strava_token)
  print(id)
  print(resolution)
  print(.Last.error)
  print(.Last.warning)

  # Accessing the data  
  
  my_acts <- get_activity_list(strava_token)
  df_name <- get_activity_streams(my_acts,
                             strava_token,
                             id = id,
                             resolution = resolution)
  
}
```

The code makes the connection to Strava and I'm able to authorize the connection, but it then stops. The five print lines added for debugging all, and I was given the error that "Object "high" not found".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a general note, it would help others to help you if instead of "not work as it should" you'd be bit more specific and describe what's the expected behaviour and how exactly the current state differs. If the problem here is not being able to access `strava_token`, `my_acts` and  `df_name`  values outside of the `generate_strava_session_data()` function, then all those assignments in your function are targeting local objects that are only visible within that function.  You could update your function to return those objects, i.e. as a list, and then work with returned values.

Comment: I agree on the general note, I was a bit sloppy. Feedback is appreciated @margusl. 

The function is supposed to generate a data frame called `df_name`. It does that outside the function (the first code chunk); `strava_data` is created. 

**The problem** is that this does not work inside the function. It makes the connection to Strava, and I'm able to authorize it. The code stops after that, and the code from `my_acts` and down does not run. 

I tried to debug further, and I get the error: "Object ' "resolution" ' is not found. This is character string, either "high", "low", or "medium".

Comment: Details added to the question, @yacc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, assignments in function are only visible in local environment, i.e. in the function itself. Same applies to objects you pass as function arguments -- altering those inside your function does not change object values in global environment. The return value of the function is the value of the last evaluated expression or explicit `return()` call, in other words your function should end with something like

```r
  ...
  get_activity_streams(my_acts,
                       strava_token,
                       id = id,
                       resolution = resolution)
}
```

(no assignment)
or

```r
  ...
  return(df_name)
}
```

There's also `<<-` operator that would allow you to alter global environment objects from functions, but generally, one should try to avoid such side effects as much as possible, this also applies to loading libraries inside a function.

Without knowing what happened next in your code, it's difficult to guess if you attempted to use functions return value or assumed that the object passed as a `df_name` argument would hold the dataset. A working example might look something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rStrava)

generate_strava_session_data <- function(resolution = "medium", id = NULL){
  if (file.exists('.httr-oauth')){
    # use cached token, if exists
    stoken <- httr::config(token = readRDS('.httr-oauth')[[1]])
  } else {
    # load secrets from environment variables, 
    # .Renviron file of current project is one convenient option to set those up
    stoken <- httr::config(
      token = strava_oauth(Sys.getenv("STRAVA_APP_NAME"), 
                           Sys.getenv("STRAVA_CLIENT_ID"), 
                           Sys.getenv("STRAVA_APP_SECRET"), 
                           app_scope="activity:read_all",
                           cache = TRUE))
  }
  # limit request to past 10 days
  my_acts <- get_activity_list(stoken, 
                               after = Sys.Date() - as.difftime(10, units = "days"))
  streams_df <- get_activity_streams(my_acts,
                                     stoken = stoken,
                                     id = id,
                                     resolution = resolution)
  # function's return value is return() argument or
  # the value of the last evaluated expression; 
  # otherwise it just returns NULL
  return(streams_df)
}

generate_strava_session_data() %>% 
  summarise(dist = max(distance), 
            avg_hr = mean(heartrate), 
            move_ratio = sum(moving) / n(), 
            duration = max(time) %>% lubridate::seconds_to_period(),
            .by = id) %>% 
  select(-id)
#>      dist  avg_hr move_ratio   duration
#> 1  4.6950 124.610      0.999    29M 19S
#> 2 37.2897 122.367      0.942 7H 12M 24S
#> 3  3.5909 134.767      0.996    28M 27S
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! This lead me to a solution :)